# Temporarily remove TrueCrypt boot loader

Tags: windows, security, truecrypt

Is it possible to temporarily remove/disable TrueCrypt boot loader (without removing partition encryption) and restore it later?

Comment: Why do you want this?  Can't you just hit the button to bypass the bootloader?

Comment: I want to hide the fact of TrueCrypt existence on this disk (from some not smart, but very paranoid people).

Comment: Have you seen the articles suggesting that you could modify the boot-loader's strings?  https://www.anti-forensics.com/modify-truecrypt-encryption-boot-loader-strings/

Comment: @Zoredache, don't know what you mean